# Pass different generic types to function

Tags: kotlin

I have a function in Kotlin that can take a generic object as a parameter. The two objects are unrelated and do not share any base types. They both however implement the same functions. I would like to re-use those functions within my function. Something along these lines:

```
fun storeUser(datastore: Any) {
   datastore.storeName("John")
}

// Call the function
val datastore1 = DataStore1()
storeUser(datastore1)

val datastore2 = DataStore2()
storeUser(datastore2)
```

Both the DataStore1 and DataStore2 have a function called "storeName". Is there a way in Kotlin to re-use this function in the storeUser function? I tried playing around with Generics but this does not seem possible.

The example code above is simple. In my real app, there are many more functions beside storeName. If I can't have a common function to store my data, I will need to create two separate functions and duplicate the storage for both. That kind of sucks.

Comment: If you wrote the `DataStore` classes, the simplest things to do would be to have them implement the same interface.

Comment: Would be. Except DataStore is provided by a third.party library that I cannot change.

Comment: @AndroidDev just overload the functions, or check and do smart-casts. That are the only two ways. But if you do checks then you can't check them at compile time, the exceptions will raise on Runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a common interface for both classes. If they are provided by a thid-party library, you could wrap them in your own classes and interface.

If you don't want to do that, you could just check the type of the parameter in the `storeUser` function:

```
 fun storeUser(datastore: Any) {
   when(datastore) {
     is DataStore1 -> datastore.storeName("John")
     is DataStore2 -> datastore.storeName("John")
     else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
   }
 }
```

But note that if you have another datastore in the future, you will need to add one more `is` clause to this function. That makes this code not very maintainable...

**Better solution**

If you create an interface `Datastore`:

```
interface Datastore {
  fun storeName(name: String)
}
```

and the make your datastores implement it:

```
class Datastore1 : Datastore {
  //Datastore1.storeName implementation
}

class Datastore2 : Datastore {
  //Datastore2.storeName implementation
}
```

Then, you don't need to check the types in `storeUser` function. Just change its parameter type to `Datastore`:

```
fun storeUser(datastore: Datastore) {
  datastore.storeName("John")
}
```

**If Datastore1 and Datastore2 are provided by a third-party library**, you can wrap them in your own classes and implement your `Datastore` interface:

```
class FirstDatastore : Datastore {

  private val datastore = DataStore1()

  override fun storeName(name: String) {
    datastore.storeName(name)
  }

}

class SecondDatastore : Datastore {

  private val datastore = DataStore2()

  override fun storeName(name: String) {
    datastore.storeName(name)
  }

}
```

So you can call your function using your classes:

```
val datastore1 = FirstDatastore()
storeUser(datastore1)

val datastore2 = SecondDatastore()
storeUser(datastore2)
```

Comment: Great! But one should note that we can pass anything into this function, and this cannot be checked in compile-time. At runtime it may cause `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Of course. That's why I recommend using a common interface.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even using my own class with its own interface would still require that in that class I have to differentiate between DataStore1 and DataStore2, which essentially duplicates the code. Your second solution also duplicates the code.

Comment: If you are crazy enough, you can do this dynamically without duplication, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment to the question, it would really be better to write a common interface for these classes. If that's not possible because the classes come from an external dependency, the second best thing to do would be to wrap the code as Héctor did.

Kotlin is a statically typed language, so unfortunately wrapping code like this results in a lot of duplication. If you didn't want to write a new wrapper for every new instance of the `DataStore`, you could use reflection to call it dynamically. This way you only have to write the definition once. However, you forego all the compile-time benefits of static checks, so it's not really a good idea. It was good to do as an exercise though.

```
class WrappedDataStore<T : Any>(private val dataStore: T) {
    private fun callDynamically(methodName: String, vararg args: Any?) {
        val argTypes = args.map { it?.let { it::class.java} }.toTypedArray()
        dataStore.javaClass
            .getMethod(methodName, *argTypes)
            .invoke(dataStore, *args)
    }

    fun storeName(name: String) = callDynamically("storeName", name)
}

fun <T : Any> storeUser(dataStore: WrappedDataStore<T>) =
    dataStore.storeName("John")

fun main() {
    val one = WrappedDataStore(DataStore1())
    val two = WrappedDataStore(DataStore2())

    one.storeName("foo")
    two.storeName("bar")

    storeUser(one)
    storeUser(two)
}

class DataStore1 {
    fun storeName(foo: String) = println("DataStore1 $foo")
}

class DataStore2 {
    fun storeName(bar: String) = println("DataStore2 $bar")
}
```

Output:

```
DataStore1 foo
DataStore2 bar
DataStore1 John
DataStore2 John
```